# Select values of a column in an object json then convert it to array AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, json

this is my object  i want to select value of quantity and type i don't know how if i have to make a matrix then place every value in the martix cell am a begginer in AngularJs , Thank you

```
[
    {
        id: 15,
        nom: "azerty",
        type: "azerty",
        quantity: 456,
        prix: 25296
    },
    {
        id: 21,
        nom: "sdqs",
        type: "qsdqsd",
        quantity: 102,
        prix: 52
    }
]
```

Comment: Once you select `quantity`, what do you want to do with it? Do you want to add it to your scope? Show it in your view? Can you post more of your code/give more context?

Comment: actually i want to use the values in a chart

Comment: for now  all i want to see is  the values in console.log()

Comment: can you post an example array showing how you want the results

Comment: var quanity = [456, 102]; and var type = ["azerty","qsdqsd"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var x = [
    {
        id: 15,
        nom: "azerty",
        type: "azerty",
        quantity: 456,
        prix: 25296
    },
    {
        id: 21,
        nom: "sdqs",
        type: "qsdqsd",
        quantity: 102,
        prix: 52
    }
];

var type = [];
var quantity = [];

x.forEach(function(item, index) {
    type.push(item.type)
    quantity.push(item.quantity)
    if(index == x.length-1){
        console.log("type: ",type);    //type: ['azerty','qsdqsd']
        console.log("quantity: ",quantity);    // quantity : [456,102]
    }
})

// once forEach is done you'll have type=[azerty,qsdqsd]  and quantity = [456,102]
```

Comment: just glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this:

```
var initialObject = [
 {
  id: 15,
 nom: "azerty",
 type: "azerty",
   quantity: 456,
 prix: 25296
},
{
 id: 21,
 nom: "sdqs",
  type: "qsdqsd",
 quantity: 102,
 prix: 52
 }
 ];

var newArray = {};

var createNewArray = function() {
    angular.forEach(initialObject, function(value, key) {
       newArray.push(value.quantity);
       newArray.push(value.type);
    })
}

//Should produce {456, azerty, 102, qsdqsd}
```

So if you just wanted a `quantity` array, just change `newArray` to `quantity`, and remove `newArray.push(value.type);`. Similar thing with `type`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your problem has nothing to do with AngularJS itself. You can transform data using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/). 
Here is an example built using lodash (btw, I added one more array element to show how groupBy works):

```
var docs = [
    {
        id: 15,
        nom: "azerty",
        type: "azerty",
        quantity: 456,
        prix: 25296
    },
    {
        id: 21,
        nom: "sdqs",
        type: "qsdqsd",
        quantity: 102,
        prix: 52
    },
    {
        id: 22,
        nom: "sdqs",
        type: "qsdqsd",
        quantity: 99,
        prix: 52
    }
];

var newDocs = _.map(docs, function(x) {return {type: x.type, quantity: x.quantity};});
var result = _.groupBy(newDocs, 'type');

console.log(result);
```

And the output looks like this:

```
{"azerty":[{"type":"azerty","quantity":456}],"qsdqsd":[{"type":"qsdqsd","quantity":102},{"type":"qsdqsd","quantity":99}]}
```

Not sure what kind of chart library do you use and what input it expects but with lodash you will be for sure able to shape your data in any possible form.

**UPDATE:**

BTW, if you change map function a bit you can get type->quantity mapping as array (don't copy my code style :) ):

```
var newDocs = _.map(docs, function(x) {var tmp = {}; tmp[x.type] = x.quantity; return tmp;});
```

Output is the following:

```
[{"azerty":456},{"qsdqsd":102},{"qsdqsd":99}]
```

Comment: i thought maybe if i can retreive the quanity data in a an array then type data in array maybe i could use it in nvd3 chart

Comment: it all depends on library and type of chart. I haven't used nvd3 but if you look in examples, you will see that each chart expects different input.

Comment: do you know a library less complicated in charts i want to view  in every `type` how much `quantity` ps i know that's too much to ask .. so feel free to do what you want !! anyway Thank you for everything

Comment: nvd3 does not look complicated. you can use pie chart (http://nvd3.org/examples/pie.html). all you need to do is just to transform your data into required format (i.e., {label: x.type, value: x.quantity}) using lodash map function (see my answer)

Comment: i think your solution is the one i should accept it i find out that i was in a deadend  until i came back here to tell  you please  how do we use lodash with angular :'(

Comment: "how do we use lodash with angular" - I didn't quite understand your question. Just add reference to lodash sources and that's it. In my answer there is also a code snippet to transform your data into form that piechart understands.

Answer (score 1):

Hello first of all **what you have is already an array of objects** , so I think that you dont need to create *two other arrays and finally have 3 arrays*.

*Let's say that we keep your **object** on your question, and name it **myData**, we have*:

**If you want to log type & quantity values**

```
myData.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item.type+'  +item.quantity);
})
```

**or show the values Into your html template:**

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="item in myData">
  <td>
     {{item.type}}
  </td>
  <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
</tr>
```

Hope helps,good luck.

Comment: yeah i know the  problem am trying to using in a chart  so  like am using a loop inside the data of the chart

Comment: Ok, but you already have your array , i still dont see the urgent to split it to two others. But its ok , since you found solution to your problem.